# Can I convert an array in such a way to Pointer and return a pointer to a constant?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Can I convert an array in such a way to Pointer and return a pointer to a constant ?  It is right in terms of memory allocation ?

```
const int* convert_vector_to_pointer(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& v)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it = v.begin();
    int* a = new int[2*v.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(; it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(i < 2*v.size())
        {
            a[i] = (*it).first;
            a[i + 1] = (*it).first;
            i += 2;
        }
    }
    const int* b = const_cast<const int*>(a);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: You would be likely far better served to just return a `std::vector<int>`, and skip all the dynamic allocation junk.

Comment: To clear something up, the variable `a` is _not_ an array. It can be _used_ as an array, just as a proper array can be used as a pointer. And why not use a `std::vector` (and `const std::vector`) instead?

Comment: There is one function in the Qt, which requires const Int * parameter to the QPolygon pol; pol.setPoints(2, array). Function has the form void setPoints( int nPoints, const int * points )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your function is that you allocate the array within the function and return a `const` pointer to it.  Either one by itself is fine, but together it means that the calling code is going to get tasked with `delete`ing a `const` object, and that's undefined behavior.  So no your example is not really right.